# How to get the store id for customoptions?

Tags: magento2.2, custom-options

I have 3 languages in my site. I need to add different titles based on language. If I add through back end it will take much time (more than 300 values I have to enter for each product). If I get the store id I can add it through the script. But I am not getting the store ID. Can anyone help to get this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require dirname(FILE) . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
class customOptions extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{ 
    public function launch() 
    { 
        state = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State'); //instance of state 
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of Object manager 
        $productId = 17; 
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
        $file = fopen("test.csv","r");
        $valuesArray = fgetcsv($file); 
        for($i =0;$i<count($valuesArray) ;$i++)
        { 
            $values = [ 'record_id'=>$i, 'title'=>$valuesArray[$i], 
            'price'=>0, 'sku'=>$valuesArray[$i], 'price_type'=>"fixed", 
            'sort_order'=>$i, 'is_delete'=>0 ]; $finalArray[] =$values;
        } 
        fclose($file); 
        foreach ($product->getOptions() as $custom_option)
        { 
            if ('test' == $custom_option->getTitle())
            {
                $custom_option_values = $custom_option->getValues();
                $custom_option->setValues($finalArray); $product->save();
            }
        } 
        return $this->_response;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please upload your code which you used.

Comment: <?php
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: class customOptions extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http  implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface 
{
   public function launch()
    {
  $state = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State'); //instance of state
  $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of Object manager
        $productId = 17;
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
  $file = fopen("test.csv","r");

Comment: $valuesArray = fgetcsv($file);
  for($i =0;$i<count($valuesArray) ;$i++){
   
   $values = [
                'record_id'=>$i,
                'title'=>$valuesArray[$i],
                'price'=>0,
    'sku'=>$valuesArray[$i],
                'price_type'=>"fixed",
                'sort_order'=>$i,
                'is_delete'=>0
            ];
   $finalArray[] =$values;

Comment: }
fclose($file);
  foreach ($product->getOptions() as $custom_option) {
   if ('test' == $custom_option->getTitle()) {
    $custom_option_values = $custom_option->getValues();
    $custom_option->setValues($finalArray);
    $product->save();
   }
  }
  return $this->_response;
 }
}

Comment: You can edit your question and upload your code :)

Comment: @Dilip I have added your code from your comments please check it if there is something missing then please update it from your end!

Comment: Hi I am setting the store id by $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId(6)->load($productId);
But still entries are creating in all stores.